# Android Add Yes/No box to listView.setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, dialog

I've been trying a lot of things to try get this working, but basically I have a list view displaying an SQLiteDb. Each row of the database is clickable as I want to be able to copy it into another table in the database. This function is working fine. My problem is that I want a Yes/No box to appear so as to confirm it before it gets copied in. I have gone through numerous tutorials and been on here searching for solution, but none that I can fit in. Here is the code I have sitting inside my displayListView() method. Thanks in advance!

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the
            // result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            dbHelper.addToPlanner(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("band")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("day")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("stage")),
                    cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("stime")),
                    cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ftime")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("planner")));

            String displayMe =
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("band"));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    displayMe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

After taking a break for a few minutes of course I figured it out!! I had to divide up my dialog box declaration and method and declare things here and there. Here's how I got it working, hope it helps someone else out.

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
                int position, long id) {        


            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            final String band = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("band"));
            final String day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("day"));
            final String stage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("stage"));
            final double stime = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("stime"));
            final double ftime = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ftime"));
            final String planner = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("planner"));

            builder.setTitle("Add To Planner")
            .setMessage("Add To Planner")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    dbHelper.addToPlanner(band, day, stage, stime, ftime, planner);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();




            String countryCode = 
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("band"));


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating an alert dialg. here is a good link to help: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, but I figured it out, just needed to step back for a minute!

Answer (score 0):

put this method in your class and call onclick of list item

public void alertDilog(final int position)
    {

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Creating alert Dialog with two Buttons

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FavoritesProperty.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

            // Write your code here to execute after dialog

        }
    });
    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog

            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();



}
```